Creating Geojson polygon string in CSV format ‏
I am trying to receive a layer a polygons output in geojson format, in a new geometry attribute table field at my project in Qgis.
I used Chatgpt to try and find a tool or a way in Qgis to add a column in a specific layer's attribute table, that shows the polygon's Geojson string for each entity in the layer, actually creating a new column that contains the string similar to the example template:
{"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-105.031425, 39.616609], [-105.034665, 39.61662], [-105.034641, 39.617029], [-105.031402, 39.617033], [-105.031425, 39.616609]]]]} 

I used this code the Chatgpt gave me in the field calculator, the new field was set to "string" in the output field type.
IF (
num_rings($geometry) > 0,
'{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [' ||
    array_to_string(
        array_foreach(
            generate_series(1, num_rings($geometry)),
            '[' ||
                array_to_string(
                    array_foreach(
                        generate_series(1, num_points(geometry_n($geometry, @element))),
                        '[' ||
                            x(point_n(geometry_n($geometry, @element), @element)) || ',' ||
                            y(point_n(geometry_n($geometry, @element), @element)) ||
                        ']'
                    )
                ) ||
            ']'
        )
    ) ||
']'
) || ']}',
'')

The thing is that this code gives me an output with some missing info for all polygons, an example of how it looks:
{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-105.029136,39.611863],[-105.029136,39.611863],,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,],[[-105.029136,39.611863],[-105.029136,39.611863],,]} 

{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-105.037676,39.624338],,,,,,,,,,,,,]}

When I used the - "geom_to_wkt($geometry)" function in the field calculator, the full WKT string appeared in the new column with no issues.
Is there a way to solve this so it can show me the full complete string properly in Geojson? I am using Qgis 3/28/5 Firenze version.
Here is an example of what I wished to receive:

Here is the code output with the wired string:


Your AI seems to have mixed up the variables in the nested functions.
In x(point_n(geometry_n($geometry, @element), @element)) one @element should refer to geometry index, and second @element to point index.
I don't know QGis syntax in detail, maybe you can rename first @element at the beginning of lambda using with_variable.
